# converting 0.000 number into milliseconds in excel

Tags: excel, milliseconds

I have acquired some data at a rate of 200Hz and instead of time stamps it gives me the time in 0.000 format:

```
0.0
0.005
0.010
0.015
and so on...
```

I have tried to convert this to time format (using =TIME(,,A1)) but it ignores the values after the dot (the milliseconds) and only calculates the time in hh:mm:ss. This gives me a bunch of numbers with the exact same value and I can't visualize my signal properly on a chart or do any further analysis.

Does anyone know how can this be solved?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: how do you want to display the final converted value? hh:mm:ss:mmm?

Comment: 0.005 of what? hours? days? weeks?

Comment: So multiply the time-stamp values by 1000 and label the x axis on your chart `milliseconds`.  I can't see that any of the usual time (let alone date) formats are necessary or desirable for your needs.

Comment: Hi everyone! Thanks for your replies! To 'mehow' yes. To 'popovittsj' 0.005 would mean seconds (and so milliseconds). To 'High Performance Mark' I have acquired these signals during a patient's surgery and so time is important to me to compare to the times when certain drugs were given or certain events happened.

Answer (score 3):

If **A1** contains 0.001 and this represents 1 millisecond, then in another cell enter:

**=A1/86400** and format this cell as Custom hh:mm:ss.000

Answer (score 0):

To extract the seconds you can do:

```
=FLOOR(A1,1)
```

To extract the milliseconds you can do:

```
=MOD(A1,1)*1000
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still don't seem to be able to convert that into time format...

Comment: Can excel maybe understand that as millisecond to add to the other time?